# How do I find out which program is causing the PC speaker to beep?

Tags: linux

How can I trace which program is making the computer beep periodically?

Is beeping usually done by writing something to `/dev/tty*`? How can I monitor which programs are writing to `/dev/tty*`?

The beep is not at the same frequency as when I do `printf '\a' > /dev/tty1`.

It vanishes on `rmmod pcspkr` and reappears on `modprobe pcspkr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this [script](https://superuser.com/questions/451496/how-do-i-strace-the-whole-system/451521) (try with caution)

```
function ppid() { cat /proc/"$1"/status | grep PPid: | grep -o "[0-9]*"; };
function pidtree() { P=$1; while [ "$P" != "1" ]; do echo $P; P=`ppid $P`; done; echo 1; };
strace -fe execve `( pgrep ''; pidtree $$ ) | sort | uniq -u | sed 's/^/-p /'`
```

I found out that ImageMagick's "import" is periodically taking screenshots and causing beeps. Added `-silent` — now beeps gone.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux and most UNIX based OSes, just printing the BELL character (Ctrl+G or '\a') will trigger a beep.

This is implemented through an `ioctl()` syscall, which is in your shell (bash, etc. support this). The syscall then goes through the kernel and is finally implemented by the `pcspkr` device, a kernel module. You can see `pcspkr` loaded with `lsmod` and unload it with `modprobe -r` or `rmmod`.

Don't even think about /dev/tty when thinking about beeps, because even headless programs that aren't bound to a TTY can produce a beep. Run `strace -eioctl bash` and in the bash prompt run `echo ^a`. You'll see that producing a beep is a simple but fairly specific `ioctl()` call (`#include` `<sys/ioctl.h>` and `<linux/kd.h>` if writing a C/C++ program to do this.)

References:

1. http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node83.html
2. http://www.linuxplayer.org/2010/04/beep-your-pc-speaker-in-linux

Comment: So, how to reliably find out what program requests a beep? Should I try to strace the whole system?

Comment: Well you can try running `fuser /dev/tty*` and `fuser /dev/console` and  go from there, but your signal to noise ratio is going to be fairly heavily favoring "noise" (a lot of activity going on that isn't beeps). Unfortunately you can't easily identify which function calls are being called on a device by which programs using `fuser` or `strace` unless you wrap every command in `strace`... so... you probably need something like `dtrace` or `systemtap` or `kprobes` to see which function calls/ioctls are being made on a given device.

Comment: Only "getty"s and "Xorg" seems to be listening to /dev/tty and /dev/console.